# Placing a RequireJS define in TypeScript to call from javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

We're half TypeScript (most of our code) and half JavaScript (we use Sencha Ext JS for our UI). And we use RequireJS to load our js files.

I want to have the following in my javascript:

```
define(["../../scripts/ribbon", "./menu-handler"], function (ribbon, handler) {
```

Where menu-handler.ts is as follows:

```
export module App.editor.menu {

    export class File {
        isOpenEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        openClicked() {
            debugger;
        }
    }

    define([], function () {
        return {
            handler: new File()
        };
    });
}
```

The problem is that typescript has no idea what that define is. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requirejs type definitions from DefinitelyTyped : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/

You can install them using `npm i -D @types/requirejs`.

Comment: Yep, have that. It still says it doesn't recognize define()